# I don't receive the email of sender who submit the form with details (name,email,message)?

Tags: express, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer for sending email, but email of sender is not receiving by using req.body.email.

See [image: screenshot]

This is my code:

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.email, // sender address
    to: "btazeem@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "New message from Code4Share visitor ", // Subject line
    text: req.body.message // plaintext body
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did the UI pass the data variable name "email" ? Show the UI form code and console.log(req.body) output.

Answer (score 0):

Your req.body.email may have same value as btazeem@gmail.com